# images are not displayed in Testflight

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, testflight

Upload your iOS app to Testflight, faced with the problem that the app is missing all images: logos, added my icons, pictures, etc. During the development of such a problem is not met. What to do in such a situation? Developing with react-native

I open my app in testflight and everything is fine. But images are missing

P.S. Only static images disappeared. The images I get in base64 format from the server are displayed well

Comment: P.S. Only static images disappeared. The images I get in base64 format from the server are displayed well

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue adding a static folder path with all app's assets to `package.json`:

```
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets"
    ]
}
```

Then I used [React Native CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cli) to link my assets:

`react-native link`

And it seems it works for me every time when I update my bundle. Hope it helps!

Comment: how do I access my images later? Now I do something like this: `export const IconEmail = require('../screens/assets/menuIcons/iconMail.png');`

Comment: Then I use this constant in other pages and use the Image component to draw

Comment: You're doing right. You should use 'require' to get a specific asset, when RNPM should just link your assets to iOS/Android projects automatically. Try to add a general source code path and check locally in production build.